# No response after sending interview re-confrim email

Tags: interviewing

I set the interview schedule about 2 months ago, the date we set is next week.
(Dec.8.)

I just wanted to get re-confirm the interview schedule since we haven't talked each other about 2 months.

I emailed them to make sure they are still available for that interview date and time.

I sent the email this Monday- haven't heard from back by now.
I don't understand why they don't answer to my email.

Should I email them again?
I'd love to work for the company, but I don't know how to handle this unexpected situation.

Comment: Only barely a dupe but it covers the general tactics available for following up and that's all that can realistically be answered here.

Answer (score 6):

**Call the company to ask a question about the interview.** That way you'll have direct contact and you'll have a legitimate reason to call as well. Of course, your question has to make sense, otherwise they'll think you're not that smart.

> Hi sir, I'll have an interview at [date] and I wanted to ask with whom the interview will be and how long it's approximately going to take so I can make sure to prepare myself well.

Maybe this is not the best example, but I don't know what your job role will be or if you have any questions about the interview or the role.

Comment: You can follow this advice without the need to invent a question. Simply calling to confirm is still perfectly legitimate, especially considering it was some time ago. "Hi, my name is [name] and we scheduled an interview some time ago for [date]. Can I confirm the interview date and time."